# IOS: Take a picture and send a email by UIActivityView

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, email

After taking a picture in the application itself, I want to send this photo (attach) by email with `UIActivityView`.

Below is the code I'm using. It takes a picture within the Project but I need to get (send) the picture that I just took by the App in developing.

```
(IBAction)shareImage:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *image = [***UIImage imageNamed:@"zzzzz.png"***];
    NSString *message = @"yyyyyyy";
    NSArray *postItens = @[image, message];
    UIActivityViewController *objVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                       initWithActivityItems:postItens applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:objVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This is sort of the code that I take to pick a picture:

```
(void) useCamera{if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;imagePicker.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage,nil];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker
                                animated:YES];
    newMedia = YES;
}


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) pickerdidFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{ 
    NSString *mediaType = [infoobjectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
    {
        UIImage *image = [infoobjectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        imageView.image = image;
 if(newMedia)UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,self,@selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),nil);}else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]){// Code here to support video if enabled}}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? I'm not sure what your problem is. This code should present the sharing sheet, and one of the options is email, if the device has an email account configured.

Comment: When I press to load the email with the sharing sheet, the attach load with one picture in the project (zzzz.png). But I want to attach the picture that I pick immediately before.

Comment: But you are the one who is saying `zzzz.png`. If that is not the picture you want, don't say that.

Comment: So, What's the code I use to take the immediately picture instead of zzzz.png?

Comment: @user3623737 , Mind formatting your code please? Indent it 4 spaces; as it stands I can barely follow it to format it correctly.

Comment: You are showing the wrong code. You need to show your code for when the picture has just been taken (`didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`) - that is where you acquire the picture.